# Counter in python not showing all words

Tags: python, csv, pandas, counter

A have a csv file, and I want the word count of **all** the words contained in that file in a seperate CSV with columns word, count.

So the python script I have written is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from collections import Counter
import pandas

wordslist = []
f = open('Sample.csv')
for word in f.read().split():
    wordslist.append(word)

Freq = Counter(wordslist)

A = Freq.items()

# for item in Freq.items(): 
#   print(item)

# print len(Freq)

pd = pandas.DataFrame(A)
pd.to_csv("WordCounter.csv", header=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

The number of words in the csv is 6672, which I found out as follows:

```
cat Sample.csv | wc -w
```

However, I assumed that the number of lines in the output csv of my script should also be equal to 6672 (i.e. the number of total words in my input file Sample.csv) as each word and its count is stored in one row of the output file.

But, it seems to be 1036 lower than 6672:

```
cat WordCounter.csv | wc -l
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Just to make sure, can you use a default text editor to get the word count?

Comment: `wc` considers `a a a` to be three words.

Comment: @Arengorn I don't think so. I want the count of every word. In simple words frequency analysis of all the words is what I want. Word count of default text editor would not provide such statistics.

Comment: @user2357112 Oh I see. I am dumb :( So the output file does not contains words which are not repeated I believe. But how to make sure that all the words from input file has been considered in the output file.

Comment: What does a sample line of your csv file look like? `split` only splits on whitespace by default, so `foo bar,baz foo` looks like three words to this algorithm - `"foo"`, `"bar,baz"` and `"foo"` again.

Comment: The sample.csv contains just one column. Each row in that contains an English sentence/phrase.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper len(wordslist) shows 6672 which means all words are in the wordlist.

Comment: To validate your wordlist, check `sum(Freq.values())`. That's the total number of words it found.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper: Typo fix, in case anyone gets a TypeError and gets confused: `sum(Freq.values())`.

Comment: Thanks, fortunately I was still in the edit window.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper Nevermind, I had corrected that typo. The result of sum(Freq.values()) seems to be 6672, so I believe the script is working correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each UNIQUE word is stored once on a line in the output file. There are not 6672 unique words in your file. If there were the output file would be:

```
word0 | 1
word1 | 1
word2 | 1
```

while it is actually:

```
word0 | 10
word1 | 5
word2 | 2
```

You should probably also strip punctuation etc. to get what you really want otherwise this will happen:

```
word0  | 4
word0, | 2
word0. | 3
```

edit: You can also simplify your code a little:

replace

```
wordslist = []
f = open('Sample.csv')
for word in f.read().split():
    wordslist.append(word)
```

with:

```
with open('Sample.csv') as f:
    wordslist = f.read().split()
```

Comment: Yes, I understood from the comments to my questions. But how can I verify that all the words from input file has been considered in the output file.  Also how to strip punctuations?

Comment: Yes, I was typing out my answer while you guys commented away :) I'm quite sure there are NLP libraries that have functions for this. If you want to do it yourself you can iterate through the file, ignoring any character `c` which is  `c not in string.letters and c not in string.whitespace`.

Comment: I've seen people recommend http://www.nltk.org/index.html, if you don't want to tackle the thorny tokenization problems yourself.

Comment: @AskeDoerge PeterDeGlopper Thanks a lot,